# Changing height of Foundation form input field from

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation. Where I make a form the input field are very high like 40px. I want to make the less height like around 26px. I looked in the css setting file but you can change a lot but not the height. When I add the css code below it works in Chorme, but in FireFox the bottom part of the texted is hidden.

```
input {
    height: 26px;
}
```

Does anyone have a idee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest and brutest (most brutey?) way to do it is:

```
input {
    height: 26px !important;
}
```

in your `app.scss` and compile your css.

However, there is a better way..

Check in the file at `/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_forms.scss` and you'll see that the height of form elements is based on the font-size and form-spacing

```
height: ($input-font-size + ($form-spacing * 1.5) - rem-calc(1));  // line 121
```

Which by default (in the same file) are:

```
$form-spacing: rem-calc(16) !default;    // line 14
$input-font-size: rem-calc(14) !default; // line 26
```

These can be found and uncommented in your `_settings.scss` file (same directory as your `app.scss`) to be overriden there before compiling again.  Test well because these are general settings that will have an effect on most (if not all) form elements.

On the plus side, in your `_settings.scss` file they are immune from updates to the framework files, and will give you more consistency in your site-wide styles.